# Is it normal for Pak Choi (Bok Choy) seedlings to come up so varied in colour and leaf shape?

Tags: vegetables, seedlings, cabbage

It's my first time with Pak Choi (Bok Choy) and so I don't know what seedlings *normally* look like. But should they be *this* varied in shape and colour?

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about Pak Choi either, but I have a stupid question: you didn't by chance purchase some kind of variety pack? Or from a non-professional/seed-specialist? Except for those cases, I'd expect seeds from the same lot to look more uniform...

Comment: out of curiosity, are they all really growing up to be pak choi? I once got a seed packet labeled broccoli that turned out to be more like collards (or some other leafy something-or-other).

Comment: please add an photo with an (much) higher resolution. It may be possible to get the variety of the plant from the first normal leaves.

Comment: Yep, and even if you have quality seed, some will be purplish while others are a lighter green. And if you live in the right area and let a couple bolt, you will have them growing wherever they find it convenient. I have one volunteer about 2 ft across living by the finishing compost heap.

Answer (score 3):

I've grown Pak Choy a few times and I get a bit of colour variation. I've found, with other plants as well as pak choy, that it usually has to do with sun exposure. Perhaps a shadow is being cast across a few of them for parts of the day? I have a coriander plant, for example, that has very pale leaves in the part that is behind a pole and the greenest of green leaves in the part that gets good sun!

Answer (score 1):

I had it few times, bought in a nursery, and they were exactament so. the guy explained that part of these were behind a pole of the greenhouse so got less sun.

Then I have grown from seed, it was impossible to put them all in the same position and the result was the same. But in fact, places to stay, they have grown regularly, beautiful and healthy.